# Docker runs PostgreSQL in "trust" mode

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I am currently learning docker and trying to run a docker container with the PostgreSQL database. I managed that once, and everything seemed to work fine. After some time, I tried to run another docker container with almost identical settings, however, it didn't go as expected. My problem is that now, whenever I try to run PostgreSQL container, **initdb** initializes the database in "trust" mode and accepts any connections without the password.

So far, I've tried running the command from the console:

```
docker run --name some-postgres -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mysecretpassword -p 32000:5432 -d postgres:14.5-alpine
```

As well as running the **docker-compose.yaml**:

```
services:
  db:
    container_name: Test_container
    image: postgres:14.5-alpine
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "32000:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: mysecretpassword
```

Additionally, I tried ordering tags differently, different images, and different values, cleaning docker: removing all containers, images, and volumes, and even reinstalling docker, however, whenever I inspect logs of a newly created container, I get:

```
sh: locale: not found
2022-08-16 09:35:50.709 UTC [30] WARNING:  no usable system locales were found
performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
--auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
syncing data to disk ... ok
```

One of my assumptions was that docker, for some reason, doesn't see the password I am specifying and thus starts the database in "trust" mode, however, if I add

```
environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
```

to the **docker-compose.yaml**, test_db database **is** being created.

I'd appreciate any suggestions on how to make docker run PostgreSQL containers not in a "trust" mode as it should by default if the password is specified.

---

**Juan González** pointed out:

> Note 1: The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so you may notice a password is not required when connecting from localhost (inside the same container). However, a password will be required if connecting from a different host/container.

So, according to the docs, I updated my **docker-compose.yaml** file:

```
environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: postgres
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: postgres
      POSTGRES_DB: test_db
      POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: scram-sha-256
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth-host=scram-sha-256
```

and once again tried swapping order and\or removing `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS`, but database still runs in "trust" mode.

Comment: You are unhappy about *local* connections are working, but you keep changing how *host* connections are configured.

Comment: @jjanes that might be what I am looking for. Any idea how to change local connection type?

Comment: Changing it to `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth=scram-sha-256` should set both types of connections at the same time, so I would try that.

Comment: Thanks @jjanes your comment should be edited as an answer!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @jjanes pointed out in the comment to my question, the solution is to add `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth=scram-sha-256` which would set both local and host types of connections.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Postgres' DockerHub [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/postgres):

> Note 1: The PostgreSQL image sets up trust authentication locally so you may notice a password is not required when connecting from localhost (inside the same container). However, a password will be required if connecting from a different host/container.

However, if you don't want trust mode even in local connections, you can set the `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD` environment variable to override this behavior. More info at the documentation mentioned above.

Comment: This seems to have no effect. As you have suggested, I tried adding `POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD: scram-sha-256`, but DB is still running in trust mode. Additionally, try adding `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: --auth-host=scram-sha-256` as suggested in the docs and change the position and order of these, but no luck.

Comment: Try using the `--auth-local=scram-sha-256` flag (instead of `--auth-host`) in the `POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS` env

Comment: This also didn't work, however, as jjanes mentioned in the comment above  `--auth=scram-sha-256` does work.